# halond.service failed while configuring AWS S3 server

Tags: amazon-s3

```
[root@s3server ~]# systemctl status halond
● halond.service - Halon Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/halond.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-02-23 12:13:37 IST; 3s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/tweag/halon
  Process: 4600 ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT $MAINPID (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
  Process: 4598 ExecStart=/usr/bin/halond -l $HALOND_LISTEN +RTS -s -A32m -I0 -RTS (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
 Main PID: 4598 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)

Feb 23 12:13:37 s3server systemd[1]: Started Halon Daemon.
Feb 23 12:13:37 s3server systemd[1]: Starting Halon Daemon...
Feb 23 12:13:37 s3server systemd[1]: halond.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Feb 23 12:13:37 s3server systemd[1]: halond.service: control process exited, code=exited status=200
Feb 23 12:13:37 s3server systemd[1]: Unit halond.service entered failed state.
Feb 23 12:13:37 s3server systemd[1]: halond.service failed.
```

It occurred when I was starting halond service on S3 server node in AWS S3 Set up. Any solution for this?

Thanks,

Preeti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Halond service was searching for '/var/lib/halon' folder on s3server node for service restart.

```
    # mkdir /var/lib/halon
```

After this, the halond service was running successfully.